# Time input field in form on android is inconsistent for 12/24 hour setting

Tags: javascript, android, angularjs, html, cordova

I have a Cordova application running on an Android 4.4.2, using AngularJS. I have an HTML5 time input element that shows up as a native time-picker once clicked. The text in the screen (before selecting the control) shows up as 24-hour format (independent of how I set the device time format), but the native control shows the format as 12 or 24 hour based on the device setting.

In the code below, the wakeupTime.hhmmss is a text-value for example equal to "22:34" (no sec). When selecting the control and setting for example 10:15PM in the control, 22:15:00 is shown on the web page.

```html
<input class="form-inline form-control" ng-model="wakeupTime.hhmmss" type="time" size="10" name="usr_time" ng-change="setWakeupTime()" value="{{wakeupTime.hhmmss}}">
```

I am struggling with this at multiple levels, but my main problem now is the time-format consistency. I must be doing something wrong in how I've approached it. I also struggle with the initial value of the control not being initiated correctly, so I'm doing something wrong here also, but I can live with that one.

I have screen shots, but I'm not allowed to include as I have no reputation :(